# Conditional Formatting (BarType) in Excel with VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-office, excel-2007, vba

I want to add BarType conditional formatting for my range !

I have :

```
  sheet.Range("F3").FormatConditions.AddDatabar()
```

How to add :
MinPoint
MaxPoint
BarColor
???

I tried :

```
sheet.Range("F3").FormatConditions(1).MinPoint = New ConditionValue(ConditionValueType.LowestValue, "0")
```

But It gives Error : ConditionalValue is not defined.. ??

I have following imports :

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

I am confused, since I am new to VB.NET !!
Please help.. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find valuable information on the Microsoft website on how to set a [condtional formating with VB.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404903%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and on how to set [data bar conditional formating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229709%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

On the second link, you can find how to create a databar and set min/max points :

```
'Create a data bar with default behavior.
Set cfDataBar = Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
MsgBox "Because of the extreme values, the middle bars are very similar"

'The MinPoint and MaxPoint properties return a ConditionValue object
'that you can use to change the threshold parameters.
cfDataBar.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValuePercentile, _
   newvalue:=5
cfDataBar.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValuePercentile, _
   newvalue:=75
```

Hope that helps,

Regards,
Max

Comment: Well that didn't worked.. as it was more of a VB Script type syntax.
But that solved the problem.. as I got the hint from this !

Comment: sorry, i don't know VB.Net enough compared too VBS but i'm glad it solved your issue